Q's about electrical wiring to decks
I have a small deck attached to the house and another detached deck and I'm looking to add an outlet at each.
Have some specific questions but also looking to get suggestions if any of this sounds whack... Outline of my plan:

Install new GFCI breaker for this circuit (I have a couple open slots)

Run 12/2 NMC cable within the basement and to the first exterior box (~5' straight out of the basement)

Don't need/want to use conduit within the basement


Use THWN for all exterior wiring after the first box

Use 3/4" aluminum EMT under the attached deck

The first part of this run would be parallel to the deck joists
After that, I would be running perpendicular to the deck joists.

Q: for this part of it, can/should I just drill holes through the joists? Or do I need to hang the conduit under the deck joists?




Use metal/aluminum boxes/fittings

Q: Should I be grounding these boxes? If so, can I just ground them to the same ground conductor I'm using for the receptacles?


Transition to 3/4" RMC for the underground portion that runs to the detached deck (~30' of conduit)

I know PVC would probably be better but I reeeeally don't want to dig 18+" down. RMC requires 6" of cover based on my understanding.
Use Southwire SIMpush fittings because I'm def not equipped to thread conduit...
Q: Does it make sense to wrap this conduit with something like 3M 50 Vinyl Corrosion Protection Tape? The whole thing or just the elbows that poke out of the ground?



Thanks for any/all input!

If you use RMC for all the outside parts then you ground the NM to the first box and then everything else gets ground via the conduit. In any case, stick with metal conduit and boxes. Nothing gained by PVC except a few $, and (a) metal is just plain better, (b) RMC takes care of ground, (c) RMC only 6" deep, as you already know. And why "PVC would probably be better" anyway? If it was better it wouldn't need to be buried deeper!

Whether you penetrate the joists or hang the conduit depends whether you're gonna penetrate the exterior joist first. Otherwise, its hard to run conduit into the penetrations (flexibility).

[OP]:  Thanks for the info.  I've seen many people online commenting that PVC is better for underground since it doesn't rust/corrode.  I've also heard that RMC is going to last a very long time underground...
Wondering how worried I should be about corrosion and if I should be taping the conduit to try to prevent that...
